# problema com Infinity no number_format

Tags: php

Bom uso a função 'number_format' do php, para formatar valores no padrão que eu desejo.

Faço assim:

```
number_format($valor_form, 2, '.', '');
```

O problema e que em algum momento o usuário informa um valor muito louco no formulário, e causa um erro na função, pois chega uma string 'Infinity'.

Minha dúvida é comeu verificar se é uma string, e se for tenho que trocar o valor da variável 'valor_form' para 0.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Olá, não sei se é a resposta mais correta mas tente assim.:number_format($valor_form*1, 2, '.', '');

Comment: não entendi bem o que vc tentou fazer. O que eu quero verificar e se existe um numero em $valor_form

Comment: se multiplicar uma string fica igual a 0. Tambem tem a função is_numeric()

Comment: Esse número é inteiro ou pode ter casa decimal?

Comment: bom, ele pode ser inteiro ou decimal